# Piano exercise for sequencing right hand chords with fixed top-most note

Tags: piano, chord-theory, exercises

Is there a diagram of all chords with the same melody note on top? with voice leading? with 7th?

```
Eb G C |  E G C |  E  A C  |
F  A C |  F A D |  F# A D | 
b3 5 1.   3 5 1.   3  6 1.
```

When one is playing harmony in the right hand, the melody note must be on top.  The exercise(diagram-treble clef notation) requested is to practice all common chords with C on top.  Above we have Cm C Am F then we move to Dm with D on top then D triad.

I currently play harmony L hand melody R hand.  I would like to play shells in the left hand & harmony R hand.  In order to do this from a lead sheet, one must play the melody with the pinky then the rest of the chord with the other fingers RH.  I am trying to practice all chords with C on top, all chords F on top, all chords Bb on top or
stepwise C D E F# on top.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand. What are the notes listed here the melody notes?

Comment: A diagram of all the chords would be the piano keyboard itself... This question is unclear, because you do not specify the chords you're after (there's a ton), and, given the context, it is not clear what "voice leading" is. You could identify the scale in which the piece is played, and then use [an online tool](https://www.scales-chords.com/chordid.php) to look up some of the available chords.

Comment: I think the OP wants something like a regular piano chord diagram listing, but grouped according to the highest note instead of the root note. All triads, sus4 chords, sevenths etc. that have a C note, in an inversion that has the C on top. Dbmaj7: Db-F-Ab-C, Dbmmaj7: Db-E-Ab-C, Dbmaj7sus4: Db-Gb-Ab-C, Dbmaj7-5: Db-F-G-C, ... E7+5/D: D-E-G#-C ... G7sus4/D: D-F-G-C ... F#7-5/E: E-F#-A#-C ... C7sus4/F: F-G-Bb-C ... Fm6/D: D-F-Ab-C ... It's a very long list. There are 11*10=110 three-note combinations with C on top, and 11*10*9=990 four-note combinations with C on top, inside one octave.

Comment: piiper is the only one who understands. I did develop an exercise: Eb G C, E G C, E A C, F A C to F A D, F# A D

Comment: piiper is the only one who understands. I did develop an exercise: Eb G C, E G C, E A C, F A C to F A D, F# A D, F B D, G B D to G B E, G# B E, G# C# E, A C# E.

Comment: It seems like you want to have a chord on each note of the melody... are you trying to do 'block chord' style? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_chord

Comment: @scidoc I understand your question as well but the way you wrote was a little unclear. I edited the question so you can get an answer

Comment: "with voice leading..." voice leading to where? If you make the list of chords like `Cm, Ab, etc.` with the `C` voiced on top, each of those chords can be voice lead to _any chord_. The permutations are gigantic, not practical. Worse yet you may end up with a chart of chord changes that aren't normal. @scidoc your comments example is roots by descending third which is common, but the minor/major changes are kind of atypical.

Comment: Are you wanting the top voice to be a sort of "ostinato"?  Or just an exercise, anyway?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think such an approach would be useful.  Voicing and fingering will be very dependent on context.  You won't need a block chord under every melody note.  As @Pyromonk commented, the best exercise will be lots of sight-reading of printed arrangements and transcriptions in the style you favour.  You'll find the harmony notes shared out between the two hands in various, ever-changing ways.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pattern that hits every basic triad (dim, min, maj, aug) containing the target "top pitch", with a clear voice-leading pattern that progresses chromatically through all twelve "top pitches".

```
X: 1
T: Basic triad pattern
M: 4/4
L: 1/4
K: C
|[_E_GC'][E=GC'][E_AC'][E=AC']|[=EGC'][E^GC'][EAC']2|[F_AC']2[F=AC']2|[^FAC']4||[E^G^c]
```

Considered with the initial top note as the tonic pitch, the chord pattern is
`io6 i6 (bVI)64 vi64 | I6 (I+)6 vi64 | iv IV | viio7/(bii = #i) ||`

Presumably there is a similar pattern that would work for seventh chords; however, there would be 65 chords for each different "melody" note:

1. Five common seventh chords: dim, half-dim, min, dom, maj
2. Four of them have three inversions with the top note fixed: half-dim, min, dom, maj
3. Plus the fully diminished chord, for which all inversions are enharmonically equivalent
4. Thus, 4^3 + 1 = 65